# Android layout alignment

Tags: android, layout

Could you please help me with the right layout elements alignment?

My first program.

http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2014-07-23/buk1F8wW.png

I want to align "0" button exactly under "1", "2" and "3", but i can't.

I'm using TableLayout with weight 4 and i set up layout:weight for "0" as 3 and for "." as 1.

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:weightSum="6">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:weightSum="5">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="88888888.88  "
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="5"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="40dp"
                android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="5" android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="C"
                android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_column="0"
                android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="MC"
                android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="M+"
                android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="M-"
                android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="MR"
                android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="5" android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="7"
                android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="8"
                android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="9"
                android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="X"
                android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/button10" android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="5" android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="4"
                android:id="@+id/button11" android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="5"
                android:id="@+id/button12" android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="6"
                android:id="@+id/button13" android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="/"
                android:id="@+id/button14" android:layout_column="3"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/button15" android:layout_column="4"
                android:layout_gravity="fill" android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="2" android:layout_weight="2">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_span="5" android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="2" android:layout_weight="4">
                <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="4" android:layout_weight="1"
                        >
                    <Button

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="1"
                            android:id="@+id/button16"
                            android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:id="@+id/button17"
                            android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:id="@+id/button18"
                            android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                            android:text="/-/"
                            android:id="@+id/button19"
                            android:singleLine="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:weightSum="1"
                             android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1">
                    <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:weightSum="2">
                        <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:id="@+id/button21"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:layout_column="0" android:layout_span="3" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textStyle="bold"/>
                        <Button
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                android:text="."
                                android:id="@+id/button23"
                                android:singleLine="false"
                                android:layout_column="1" android:layout_span="1" android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:weightSum="1">
                <Button
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text="="
                        android:id="@+id/button20"
                        android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="6">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="88888888.88  "
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_span="5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="40dp"
            android:gravity="right"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="C"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="MC"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="M+"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="M-"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="MR"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="X"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="+"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="/"
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="-"
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="4">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:weightSum="4">
                    <Button

                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:id="@+id/button16"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button

                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:id="@+id/button17"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:id="@+id/button18"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="/-/"
                        android:id="@+id/button19"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:weightSum="4">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:id="@+id/button21"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="."
                        android:id="@+id/button23"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="="
                    android:id="@+id/button20"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="6" >

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="88888888.88  "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="C"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="MC"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="M+"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="M-"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="MR"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="7"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="8"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="9"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="X"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="+"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>


<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="5"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="6"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="/"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="-"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_span="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="3"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:text="/-/"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TableLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:weightSum="3" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button21"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_span="3"
                        android:layout_weight="0.8"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button23"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_span="1"
                        android:layout_weight="0.6"
                        android:singleLine="false"
                        android:text="."
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="="
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

let me know the feedbacks.